Angular Component from library not working - TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'bindingStartIndex')
Created an angular library and added a component to it. Build the library and npm link it with another angular application running locally.
 TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'bindingStartIndex')
    at ɵɵelementStart (core.mjs:24125:46)
    at MyLibComponent_Template (my-lib.component.ts:14:28)
    at executeTemplate (core.mjs:11609:9)
    at renderView (core.mjs:12816:13)
    at renderComponent (core.mjs:12762:5)
    at renderChildComponents (core.mjs:12864:9)
    at renderView (core.mjs:12844:13)
    at renderComponent (core.mjs:12762:5)
    at renderChildComponents (core.mjs:12864:9)
    at renderView (core.mjs:12844:13)

All the conditions are correct: Module properly imported, component properly imported, module & component properly exported and listed in public api list of the library. Stuck up with this issue for 2 days and tried all solutions. But not working. When the templete html is made empty this error doesn't appear. Even if we use
<div>hello</div>

this issue exists. Its not working for @Component template:
<div>hello</div> 

also. html files can be seen in the source tab of the chrome window. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

please share the contents of my-lib.component.ts

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
selector: 'lib-my-lib',
standalone: true,
imports: [],
template:     <p>       my-lib works!     </p>  ,
styles: ``
})
export class MyLibComponent {
} Thanks @NarenMurali
